# Items help in DoTA

Tags: dota

I'm starting to play DoTA, and in order to not get lost in the game, I keep a hero guide open. The other day, I picked the Nerubian Assasin, and when I checked [his entry in the guide](http://www.playdota.com/guides/alt-tab-guide-to-every-agi-hero#nerubian-assassin) and started to follow the item order, I couldn't find the third item on the Core Items list.

The item functions by storing up charges every time an opponent casts a spell near by, and then you can use these charges to gain health and mana.  Additionally, it is the result of mixing other items together in a recipe.

I was unable to find that item in particular in [a more general item guide](http://www.playdota.com/items).

Can anyone identify this item for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it!

[image: Magic Wand]

It was the Magic wand, which is formed from 3 Ironwood Branches plus the Magic Stick.

Comment: @tzenes thanks for the nice edition. New in stack also.

Comment: that's what we're here for.  Also take the time to mark this answer as correct (its the checkmark next to the voting number)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean [Shiva's Guard](http://www.dotastrategy.com/item-104-ShivasGuard.html) or [Necronomicon](http://www.dotastrategy.com/item-32-Necronomicon.html)? [Here](http://www.dotastrategy.com/item.html) are all the other items

Comment: thanks. It was the Magic Wand what I was asking for. But thanks

Comment: no problem. I though you were asking about the 3 item to build for anubrak from that site